# Best solution to "hot-deploy" Apache Camel routes and beans classes?

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf

We use Apache Camel as a standalone application for ~ 2 years. It works very
well but the need to restart the process to upgrade the application each time
we add new routes becomes an issue.

We are searching for a new deployment solution that could allow us to deploy 
new routes without having to restart the main process.

There is no problem for us to rewrite our Java DSL routes in XML but the issue
is that most of them (and probably future ones too) make use of custom beans,
processors, components etc. to inject some logic that is too complex to
be expressed in pure XML/Java DSL route.

After searching through Camel documentation, hot deploying XML routes seems to
be possible with spring-boot or with Karaf/OSGI.

But i have no idea if it is possible to "hot-deploy" bean, processors,
components etc. classes that are needed by theses XML routes. OSGI/Karaf looks
promising but i have never used boths technologies and it is not easy to grasp their purpose at first glance.

Which deployment method and which technology could allow us to "hot deploy' routes and beans classes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hot-deploy Java code, then you need an application server like platform such as Apache Karaf/ServiceMix/JBoss Fuse etc or a traditional like Tomcat, JBoss, WildFly etc (for WAR files).

Then you can do a "hot deployment" as a deployment of the application.

To hot-deploy a single class or some classes inside a running JVM is harder, and you would need special tooling such as JRebel.

Comment: Are the route running inside independant CamelContexts when deployed with Apache Karaf ? And can a route make use of a bean class located inside an "osgi bundle" ? If yes then Karaf is the answer because our main concern is to not to stop others routes while deploying one. The beans classes are pretty specific to a route so we could deploy the osgi bundle containing the beans for a route just before the route and stop only this route if the bundle needs to be updated.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about how to make java beans visible for hot deployed springDSL-declared camel routes? Afaik, every deployed file (jar, war, xml) is transformed into separate OSGI bundle. And OSGI bundles don't have access to others code by default, they should describe required packages in import section in manifest file. And xml file doesn't have any

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use camel-blueprint to setup the context/route. 
By exposing your bean as osgi service, you can use those beans in routes.
I would suggest you to take a look into apache camel blueprint maven archetype and camel component archetype to get started.

Hot deploy in Apache Karaf is simple, simply drop the bundle into $KARAF_HOME/deploy and it will reload automatically.

Reference:
[camel-archetype-component](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.archetypes/camel-archetype-component/2.20.2) [camel-archetype-blueprint](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.archetypes/camel-archetype-blueprint/2.20.2)

Do let me know if this help.

PS: I don't have enough reputation for commenting hence the answer.

Comment: OK that seems to confirm my thoughts about apache karaf / OSGI. Thanks!

Comment: You might need to read some material about karaf and it's feature ecosystem to prevent  caveat happen during deployment etc.

Comment: Yes of course. I needed first to validate that the technology answer to our needs before diving to much into it.